# Python 2.7: Variable defined in previous function, receiving undefined error

Tags: python-2.7, undefined

So my variable is clearly defined in inputnfo(), why am I getting an undefined error? The try & except perhaps? I've added removed... swapped it all around and cannot seem to find the solution, and answers online seem very situation based... Thanks in advance :)

### Super New & improved edit: now getting UnboundLocalError

```
import random

alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

strgen = []

retry = 0

### Defining

def inputnfo():
    global much
    much = input('how long do you want your random word/lucky number to be: ')
    global which
    which = raw_input('would you like letters or numbers?(let,num, or mix?):').lower


def generate():
    while much > 0:
        if which == 'let':
            strgen.append(random.choice(alpha))
            much -= 1
            print '.'

        elif which == 'num':
            strgen.append(random.randint(1,9))
            much -= 1
            print '.'

        elif which == 'mix':
            mixer = random.choice([0,1])
            if mixer == 0:
                strgen.append(random.choice(alpha))
                much -= 1
                print '.'

            elif mixer == 1:
                strgen.append(random.randint(1,9))
                much -= 1
                print '.'

def finish():

    finito = ''.join(strgen)
    print 'Generation Completed!\n'

    if which == 'let':
        print 'Your randomly generated string is:' + finito

    elif which == 'num':
        print 'Your randomly generated number is:' + finito

    elif which == 'mix':
        print 'Your randomly generated Alpha-Numerical string is:' + finito

### Running

inputnfo()

while much != 0:
    generate()

finish()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the variable "much" in the function inputnfo() is local to that function alone. that is why you are getting an undefined error in the while loop. there is two solution
1. Make the variable "much" global by including the line

```
def inputnfo():
    global much
    try:
```

and then removing the argument of generate function

Or
2. Let the function inputnfo() return much and use this return value in the while loop and generate function

do the same for variable "which" 
and put a line `which = ""` befor

```
which = ""
def inputnfo():
    global much
```

Comment: I realized the global, and applied that to much which works fine, but why do I declare which as an empty string outside of my function, as well as using global?

Comment: @OsirisHex It hangs because there is no break condition in the while loop in generate function and the while loop bellow ##Running... The keyword global is used to inform the interpreter that while using that variable it should use the global ones...so if there is no global variable then it gives error..so an empty decleration